# How to disable screen automatic off in CentOS 7 when at terminal (no xde running)

Tags: centos7

When I start the computer, I'm logging in directly at the `username:` prompt. I am not launching any XDE.

How can I either completely disable the screen from shutting off, or increase the timeout to a sufficiently long time?

The only instructions I have been able to find are for various XDEs like Gnome, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable the screen blanking with `setterm -blank 0`.

Put this into `/etc/rc.d/rc.local`, make sure that file is executable and then start and enable the `rc-local` service:

```
systemctl enable rc-local
systemctl start rc-local
```

Another option would be to add `consoleblank=0` to the kernel parameter in your grub configuration.